# JavaScript regex.test Firefox vs. other browsers, different behavior

Tags: javascript, regex, cross-browser

I have following regular expression in JavaScript, which is supposed to match every letter of Czech alphabet.

```
var patt = new RegExp("[A-Za-zÁČĎÉĚÍÓŘŠŤÚŮÝŽáčďéěíóřšťúůýž]");
```

The problem is, in Mozilla this regular expression matches absolutely everything, including strings like

```
var str = "2";
```

and other string, that should not be matched.

All other browsers (tried with Chrome, Opera, IE, Safari) do return "false" for following line of code

```
var res = patt.test(str);
```

I'm really confused about this behavior, any help welcome!

Thank you

Comment: Mozilla? Do you mean Firefox? or are you still using [Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/products/mozilla1.x/)?

Comment: I mean Firefox, bad old habit, sorry.

Comment: I don't get that behavior when I test that code in Firefox 29.

Comment: That's odd. I just tested it on 4 different PC's, getting the same results on each one.

If you try executing this piece of code: http://pastie.org/9123623, over here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_test2 , press 'Submit code' and 'Try'. Do you really get 'False' as a return value in Firefox?

Your response would really help me greatly. I don't seem to be able to solve this on my own.

Comment: I get different results on W3Schools to my JS console.

Comment: It's quite possible that they encode the symbols as ASCII rather than UTF-8 which might be something like `\x02` for one of the characters which would give a 2 in the character set which would then match.

Comment: Good thought. W3Schools encodes it as `var patt = new RegExp("[A-Za-zÁ&#268;&#270;É&#282;ÍÓ&#344;Š&#356;Ú&#366;ÝŽá&#269;&#271;é&#283;íó&#345;š&#357;ú&#367;ýž]");` and here I was thinking I'd found the limits of their crapness.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Firefox are you on? from the firefox dev console (press F12) on Firefox 28.0 on Arch linux :

```
var patt = new RegExp("[A-Za-zÁČĎÉĚÍÓŘŠŤÚŮÝŽáčďéěíóřšťúůýž]");
# undefined
var str = "2";
# undefined
var res = patt.test(str);
# undefined
res
# false
```

EDIT: as mentioned in the post it is a UTF-8 / ASCII encoding error, it is encoded as:

```
var patt = new RegExp("[A-Za-zÁ&#268;&#270;É&#282;ÍÓ&#344;Š&#356;Ú&#366;ÝŽá&#269;&#271;é&#283;í‌​ó&#345;š&#357;ú&#367;ýž]");
```

by W3Cschools (who are pretty terrible, and shouldn't really be used for much).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: That's a fair point, I wasn't able to provide code formatting in a comment which is why I posted here, won't do that in future.